# Rounding the place.geometry.location value in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3, location, coordinates

I am using Google Maps API to do Reverse Geocoding (Address Lookup). My code result a extremely detail `Lat Long` as:

(-7.799250499999999, 110.40451239999993)

How to round the place.geometry.location result into a certain digit decimals?

e.g. (-7.7992505, 110.4045124)

This is the scheme of my code:

**In my HTML**

```
<div id="infowindow-content">
    <span id="place-coord"></span>
</div>
```

**In my Javascript**

```
...    
function() {
    ...
    infowindowContent.children['place-coord'].textContent = place.geometry.location;
    ...
}
...
```

I had tried to use:

```
place.geometry.location.toUrlValue(precision?:number)
```

or

```
place.geometry.location.toUrlValue(precision?:7)
```

and result some crash.

Any helps would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: have you tried the toFixed method?

Comment: `I had tried to use:` ... probably just need `place.geometry.location.toUrlValue(7)`

Comment: It works. Thank you Jarome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `precision?:number` code must be replaced by an integer.

```
place.geometry.location.toUrlValue(WriteYourDesiredPrecisionHere)
```

in this question, it sould be:

```
place.geometry.location.toUrlValue(7)
```